# scala DataFrame cast log failure warning

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logging, casting

I have a DataFrame in scala with a column of type `String`.
I want to cast it to type `Long`.

I found that the easy way to do that is by using the `cast` function:

```
val df: DataFrame
df.withColumn("long_col", df("str_col").cast(LongType))
```

This will successfully cast "1" to 1.
But if there is a string value that can't be cast to Long, e.g "some string" the result value will be `null`.

This is great, except I would like to know when this happens. I want to output a warning log whenever the casting failed and resulted in a `null` value.

And I can't just look at the output DF and check how many `null` values it has in the "long_col" column, because the original "string_col" column sometimes contains `null`s too.

I want the following behavior:

- if the value was cast correctly - all good
- if there was a non-null string value that failed to cast - warning log
- if there was a null value (and the result is also null) - all good

Is there any way to tell the `cast` function to log these warnings? I tried to read through the implementation and I didn't find any way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it like this:

```
def getNullsCount(df: DataFrame, column: String): Long = {
  val c: Column = df(column)
  df.select(count(when(c.isNull, true)) as "count").limit(1).collect()(0).getLong(0)
}

val countNulls: Long = getNullsCount(df, "str_col")
val newDF = df.withColumn("long_col", df("str_col").cast(LongType))
val countNewNulls: Long = getNullsCount(newDF, "long_col")
if (countNulls != countNewNulls) {
   log.warn(s"failed to cast ${countNewNulls - countNulls} values")
}
newDF
```

I'm not sure if this is an efficient implementation. If anyone has any feedback on how to improve it I would appreciate it.

**EDIT**

I think this is more efficient because it can calculate both counts in parallel:

```
val newDF = df.withColumn("long_col", df("str_col").cast(LongType))
val nullsCount1 = df.select(count(when(df("str_col").isNull, true)) as "str_col_count")
val nullsCount2 = newDF.select(count(when(newDF("long_col").isNull, true)) as "long_col_count")
val joined = nullsCount1.join(nullsCount2)
val nullsDiff = joined.select(col("long_col_count") - col("str_col_count") as "diff")
val diffs: Map[String, Long] = nullsDiff.limit(1).collect()(0).getValuesMap[Long](Seq("diff"))
val diff: Long = diffs("diff")
if (diff != 0) {
  log.warn(s"failed to cast $diff values")
}
```